# Novel: magnetic reversal reveals cyclops and giants in the US

Tags: story-identification, novel

Novel about a magnetic reversal. U.S. flash freezes and  Antarctica rapidly thaws and reveals ancient Cyclops and other giants. Main character is a young lady. She meets up with other people and eventually escapes to military ship in the ocean.

Comment: When did you read it?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Can you add more details? Such as when you read this and where? Do you remember the cover at all?

Comment: It was a used book when I read it several years ago. I do not remember the cover. The creatures were ones found in the bible. The people they captured were taken into the caves in the mountain.

Answer (score 5):

Antarktos Rising by Jeremy Robinson (2011) This book has almost all the things you have listed: Frozen USA though from crustal displacement instead of magnetic reversal, thawing Antarctica with return of Biblical giants, main character is a young lady (Mirabelle Whitney), the other people teams from various nations on a race to claim the continent, and lastly escape from the continent via ship.  It was pretty good as I recall, much better than I expected, and supposedly to be made into a movie per the cover.

[image]